# Console warning when migrating from the MaterialUI lab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, material-ui

When I run my MUI app, I get this error in the console

**Warning:  forwardRef render functions accept exactly two parameters: props and ref. Did you forget to use the ref parameter?**

```
import { LoadingButton } from "@mui/lab";

const LoadData = ({loading,signinHandler}) => (
  <LoadingButton loading={loading} variant="contained" sx={{ textTransform: "capitalize" }} onClick={signinHandler}>
    Login
  </LoadingButton>
)

export default LoadData
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't import Lab components like this

`import { LoadingButton } from '@mui/lab'`

Use this:

`import LoadingButton from '@mui/lab/LoadingButton'`